# On Glance You Should Not Lean

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme

**A riddle in rhyme, that's missing a line.**

> Dare think what it may seem? 
> Your sample is extreme? 
> On glance you should not lean! 
> _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ - _ _ _ - _ _ _ _!

**How is the rhyme finished? A principle undiminished.**

> Hint 1:

> The underscores may (or may not) suggest character count, and the dashes may (or may not) be spaces.

> Hint 2:

> "Sample" and "Extreme" are huge hints toward this phenomenon.

> Hint 3:

> You might be aware of this if you studied Psychology or Statistics.

Comment: Added another hint. Gaging by the downvote, this isn't as obvious as I thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing line is:

> **[Regression to the mean](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_toward_the_mean)!**

What is this?

> In statistics, it is common to find that an extreme result obtained from one sample is not necessarily repeated in the next one, in which case the second result is much closer to the arithmetical average (the 'mean') for the population.
>
>  A good example is height. If you measure the heights of a group of parents and identify two particularly tall ones who have children together, then measure the heights of all of the parents' children, the children of those two exceptionally tall parents will not necessarily be among the tallest in that second sample - they are much more likely to be closer to the average height for those children and unlikely to be outliers like their parents. (i.e. Very tall parents will not necessarily have very tall kids. Although it does sometimes happen - I'm sure everyone knows such a family - *it doesn't always...*)
>
>  Another example - a particular bugbear of mine - is the phenomenon that the results of Premier League teams often improve after sacking the manager. This is usually attributed to 'new manager bounce', implying that the new manager has made a difference to the team's results (giving teams an incentive to sack managers mid-season when they hit what might just be a 'blip' in form from which they might recover without sacking the manager). But teams who sack their managers usually do so because their results at the time are extremely terrible - they are unlikely to get even worse because they often *cannot*, so an improvement in points gained is inevitable, and their average points per game will soon become much closer to that for other teams in the division (it will 'regress to the mean').

So the moral of this puzzling poem is:

> Be wary of making sweeping conclusions based on an extreme result in your sample - remember that many measures might regress to the mean upon repetition. Use your brain as well as your eyes!
>
>  The rhyme is a useful mantra to repeat when interpreting extreme results...

Full disclosure: I am a statistician, and this is right up my alley!

Comment: You know, I'm starting to wonder if I just make riddles for you. lol. Nice explanation!